# SSRS data subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to setup a process whereby data subscriptions can be created via a stored procedure rather than through the report manager. We are planning to migrate hundreds and hundred of reports over from my old system eventually and the current data subscription model seems to have a lot of limitations.

I've done extensive googling and haven't found anyone that has actually done it themselves. I did come across an article where the subscription is created and then a procedure is used to call that subscription but this seems to be a bit of a hassle.

Has anyone managed to create a procedure that creates the data subscription and job to send out the reports?

Comment: If you are planning to use any .net application rather than using Report Manager  that will give UI to manage SSRS Subscriptions then you can consume Report Server web services that will be a proper approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an internal application to manage this process via the ssrs api, however, there are existing third party applications that can do this.

If you would like to create a dynamic recipient list for emailed reports then you can do this by using a data driven subscription with the `To:` field being pulled from a stored procedure that returns a list of emails.

You can also look at the `CreateTimeBasedSubscriptionSchedule` stored procedure in the ssrs ReportServer database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to migrate a lot of subscriptions to another system, have a look at a tool called RSScripter. With this you can easily copy reports over to another system.

To answer your question, the web services api is a better option to add subscriptions. I'm not aware this has been done via a procedure, it's certainly possible but probably unsupported and complicated.

I have been in a similar situation than what i think is yours (a lot of subscriptions, need to add/remove them automatically). I ended up completely skipping subscriptions and writing https://busyreports.codeplex.com. You can certainly use subscriptions but for me it was too many hacks needed.

Comment: The existing reports were created many years ago so we're potentially looking to migrate them over SSRS but nothing has been confirmed.